# T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, html5

Buenas y saludos a todos, estoy tratando de guardar datos a través de PHP desde un formulario HTML, el cual me esta dando el siguiente error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"INSERT INTO judiciales (n_int' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\galeanosas\ingresar.php on line 30

Les agradezco la ayuda que me puedan prestar, soy nuevo en esto, gracias!

---

**Aquí les dejo el documento HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Galeanos - Intranet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
     
<div class="header">
  <h1>GALEANOS</h1>  
</div>

<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#">Judiciales</a>
  <a href="#">Mercantiles</a>
  <a href="#">Otros</a>
</div>   
      
   <form action="ingresar.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput">N° INTERNO</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="n_interno" id="formGroupExampleInput">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">CIUDAD</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ciudad" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">JUZGADO</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="juzgado" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">5600</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="a5600" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">ID EKOGUI</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_ekogui" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">BIZAGI</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bizagi" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">DEMANDADO</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="demandado" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">DEMANDANTE</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="demandante" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">CLASE DE ACCIÓN</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="clase_de_accion" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">LLAMADO EN GARANTIA</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="llamado_en_garantia" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">ESTADO ACTUAL</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estado_actual" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">FECHA ÚLTIMA ACTUACIÓN</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fecha_ultima_actuacion" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">APELACIÓN</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apelacion" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">N° RADICACIÓN</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="n_radicacion" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">ÚLTIMA ACTUACIÓN</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ultima_actuacion" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">HONORARIOS</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="honorarios" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
  </div>
  <input type="Submit" name="Guardar" value="Guardar">
</form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Aquí el código PHP**

```
<?php
$n_interno = $_POST['n_interno'];
$ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];
$juzgado = $_POST['juzgado'];
$a5600 = $_POST['a5600'];
$id_ekogui = $_POST['id_ekogui'];
$bizagi = $_POST['bizagi'];
$demandado = $_POST['demandado'];
$demandante = $_POST['demandante'];
$clase_de_accion = $_POST['clase_de_accion'];
$estado_actual = $_POST['estado_actual'];
$fecha_ultima_actuacion = $_POST['fecha_ultima_actuacion'];
$apelacion = $_POST['apelacion'];
$n_radicacion = $_POST['n_radicacion'];
$ultima_actuacion = $_POST['ultima_actuacion'];
$honorarios = $_POST['honorarios'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "judiciales";
            $conexion = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'judiciales');

            if (!$conexion) {
            die('Error de conexión: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
            }    

$sql=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);"INSERT INTO judiciales (n_interno, ciudad, juzgado, a5600, id_ekogui, bizagi, demandado, demandante, clase_de_accion, estado_actual, fecha_ultima_actuacion, apelacion, n_radicacion, ultima_actuacion, honorarios) " .
  "VALUES ('$n_interno', '$ciudad', '$juzgado', '$a5600', '$id_ekogui', '$bizagi', '$demandado', '$demandante', '$clase_de_accion', '$estado_actual', '$fecha_ultima_actuacion', '$apelacion', '$n_radicacion', '$ultima_actuacion', '$honorarios')";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
echo 'Datos guardados.\n';
?>
```

Comment: Para concatenar en php debes usar un . y no un +, a la variable $sql quitale ese mysql_query y deja solo el string, prueba con eso y mira si te da

Comment: Gracias Camilo por tu pronta repuesta, si se pudo solucionar ese error. Ahora cuando reviso la base de datos no veo la información, porque será? y gracias de nuevo!

Comment: mysql_query($sql); debes cambiarlo a mysqli_query($sql); y creo que esta función recibe dos parámetros por lo cual debería quedar mysqli_query($conexion, $sql); no estoy seguro si recibe los dos parámetros o se puede dejar solo uno

Comment: Ahora me sale esto Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\galeanosas\ingresar.php on line 30

Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\galeanosas\ingresar.php on line 30

Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\galeanosas\ingresar.php on line 32
Datos guardados.\n

Comment: Indefinida? que extraño, por favor edita tu pregunta y muéstrame como quedó tu código luego de los cambios que hiciste

Comment: Buenos días Camilo, ya edite el código, cuando puedas lo miras, gracias!

Comment: Deja $sql de la siguiente forma (debería tener únicamente el string de la consulta): $sql = "INSERT INTO judiciales (n_interno, ciudad, juzgado, a5600, id_ekogui, bizagi, demandado, demandante, clase_de_accion, estado_actual, fecha_ultima_actuacion, apelacion, n_radicacion, ultima_actuacion, honorarios) " .
  "VALUES ('$n_interno', '$ciudad', '$juzgado', '$a5600', '$id_ekogui', '$bizagi', '$demandado', '$demandante', '$clase_de_accion', '$estado_actual', '$fecha_ultima_actuacion', '$apelacion', '$n_radicacion', '$ultima_actuacion', '$honorarios')";

Comment: Listo Camilo, así resultó, muchas gracias por tu pronta repuesta!

Comment: Me alegra que te haya funcionado, te lo he publicado como respuesta !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tenías era en que el primer mysqli_query() que tenías no estaba recibiendo una sentencia sql correcta ya que lo estabas pasando d ela siguiente forma:

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);"INSERT INTO judiciales (n_interno, ciudad, juzgado, a5600, id_ekogui, bizagi, demandado, demandante, clase_de_accion, estado_actual, fecha_ultima_actuacion, apelacion, n_radicacion, ultima_actuacion, honorarios) " .
  "VALUES ('$n_interno', '$ciudad', '$juzgado', '$a5600', '$id_ekogui', '$bizagi', '$demandado', '$demandante', '$clase_de_accion', '$estado_actual', '$fecha_ultima_actuacion', '$apelacion', '$n_radicacion', '$ultima_actuacion', '$honorarios')";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
```

De esta forma cuando el código llegaba al `mysqli_query();` que tenías dentro de la variable $sql reventaba por que no detectaba una sentencia válida.

Es por eso que debías dejar en `$sql` únicamente el string de la sentencia y asignarlo a tu `mysqli_query()` guardado en la variable `$result`, de la siguiente forma:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO judiciales (n_interno, ciudad, juzgado, a5600, id_ekogui, bizagi, demandado, demandante, clase_de_accion, estado_actual, fecha_ultima_actuacion, apelacion, n_radicacion, ultima_actuacion, honorarios) " .
      "VALUES ('$n_interno', '$ciudad', '$juzgado', '$a5600', '$id_ekogui', '$bizagi', '$demandado', '$demandante', '$clase_de_accion', '$estado_actual', '$fecha_ultima_actuacion', '$apelacion', '$n_radicacion', '$ultima_actuacion', '$honorarios')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
```

Y eso es todo, otro error que tenías era que estabas tratando de concatenar un string en PHP usando el `+`, recuerda que para JavaScript el + es el operador de concatenación pero en PHP debes usar un punto (`.`)

Comment: Gracias de nuevo @Camilo, puedes recibir puntos de mi? soy nuevo y no se como funciona.

Comment: Siendo así te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow en español, te invito a que marques la respuesta como aceptada (clicando en el chulito que encuentras debajo de las flechas de utilidad), así otros desarrolladores podrán saber que esta respuesta fue la solución a tu problema, **es importante que leas [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)**, además deberías hacer el [tour] para que sepas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio y ganes otra medalla, saludos !